# How can I call multiple number at once in Twilio using node js? I want to send my customers a pre recorded voice on call

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

```
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.calls
      .create({
         twiml: '<Response><Say>Ahoy, World!</Say></Response>',
         to: '+14155551212',
         from: '+15017122661'
       })
      .then(call => console.log(call.sid));
```

How can I modify this to accept more than one number?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can only make one call per API request, so to make calls to more than one number you will need to loop and make a request for each number. Like so:

```js
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

async function makeCalls(numbers) {
  numbers.forEach(async (number) => {
    await client.calls
      .create({
         twiml: '<Response><Say>Ahoy, World!</Say></Response>',
         to: number,
         from: '+15017122661'
       })
      .then(call => console.log(call.sid));
  });
}

const numbers = []; // An array of the numbers you want to make calls to.

makeCalls(numbers);
```